# MS Excel VBA, Out of stack space and Run-time error '-2147417848 (800 10 108)': Method 'Value' of object 'Range' failed

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

Those two problems keep cropping up when I use Worksheet_Change and Target. It happens when I delete the contents of one of the cells that I suppose Target is referring to. I'll give my code to look over, it's quite simple: (PS, relatively new to VBA, any tips would be great!)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'## Determine if change to cell Q6
If Target.Cells.count > 1 Then Exit Sub

If Target = Range("Q6") Then
    'Determine if the 1 is contained within cell Q6
    vRangeValue = Range("Q6").Value
    vStringValue = 1
    Application.EnableEvents = False

        'Paste value in R6
    If vRangeValue = vStringValue Then
        Range("R6").Value = 1
    End If

End If

'Remove 1 from R6
Range("R6").Value = 0
Range("R7").Value = 1
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

The code does what I want when I first open the sheet and type 1 in Q6 (It puts a 1 in R6 then quickly switches it back to a 0). It also puts 1 in R7 'cos it goes so fast that I wanted a check. But if I delete the contents of any cells in my sheet (as far as I can tell), I've been getting one of the two errors specified in the title.
I've tried googling but all the examples I've found are too specific to understand, so I thought I'd consult here. Thanks for any help, and sorry if I've done something stupid!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple issues here.

First, you are running out of stack space because the `Worksheet_Change` event is changing the worksheet, which fires the `Worksheet_Change` event, which changes the worksheet, which fires the `Worksheet_Change` event, which... you get the point.

One way to handle this is to add a re-entry flag that prevents the event handler from recursing. The other is (as you tried) turning off events, but see below...  My personal preference is to use a re-entry flag so I don't interfere with other events that I actually care about.

Second, the default property of a `Range` is it's `Value`.  That means the "test" here...

```
If Target = Range("Q6") Then
```

...is comparing the *cell contents*. What it is testing is whether **assigning** the `Value` in `Range("Q6")` to `Target` is `True`.  But at this point it doesn't matter, because the event handler fires in that `Application.EnableEvents = False` is below that line in your code.

This section does a bunch of superfluous work and can be condensed into a simple comparison and assignment:

```
vRangeValue = Range("Q6").Value
vStringValue = 1
'...
If vRangeValue = vStringValue Then
Range("R6").Value = 1
End If
```

I'd do something more like this:

```
Private Changing As Boolean     'Module level scope

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Changing Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 _
    Or Application.Intersect(Target, Range("Q6")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Changing = True
    If Target.Value = 1 Then
        Range("R6").Value = 1
    End If

    'Range("R6").Value = 0  '<--No clue why you do this.
    Range("R7").Value = 1
    Changing = False
End Sub
```